# How to add an array with values in Symfony2 configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I would like to add a simple list of values in a configuration files (config.yml). For example :

```
my_bundle:
    columns: ["col1", "col2"]
```

When adding the node to the configuration parser, it simply fails :

```
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');
$rootNode->arrayNode('columns')->children()->end();
```

Here is the error :

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "0, 1" under "my_bundle.columns"
```

What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to achieve a node like this, just do:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('columns')
            ->prototype('scalar')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

Comment: Nearly. I found another question mentioning the `prototype` method. In my case, the prototype has to hold `scalar` and it worked.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve then, using this code  `var_dump($config);` = `Array
(
    [columns] => Array
        (
            [0] => col1
            [1] => col2
        )

)`

Comment: Shouldn't there also be another `->end()` right after `->prototype('scalar')`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're *missing* that YaML is not a markup language, it's not even *a langauge* as such (It's a data serialization standard), so it doesn't know of any language constructs, like arrays. Its main *"tool"* to express grouping and relations between bits of data is whitespace, colons and dashes.
From the [symfony documentation page of the YaML format](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html):

```
my_bundle:
    columns: 
        - col1
        - col2
```

As I gather from this section:

> A YAML file is rarely used to describe a simple scalar. Most of the time, it describes a collection. A collection can be a sequence or a mapping of elements. Both sequences and mappings are converted to PHP arrays.
>
> Sequences use a dash followed by a space:
>
> `-` PHP
>
> `-` Perl
>
> `-` Python
>
> The previous YAML file is equivalent to the following PHP code:

```
array('PHP', 'Perl', 'Python');
```

Comment: `["PHP", "Perl", "Python"]` is equivalent to your notation in YAML. And what I was asking is indeed possible as Touki answered it. All you have to do is specify which kind of data the array contains. In my case string/scalar.

Comment: @i.am.michiel: misread the question, in that case. I thought `['col1', 'col2']` wasn't working, have you tried explicitly setting the type, too? `- !!str col1`?

Comment: No problem. And the parsing problem was not on the YAML-side but on the Symfony-side. All I had to do was add a conversion option in the YAML-parser as noted in Loki's answer.