# Symfony config: How to validate an configuration where values can be absent but if present have to be of defined kind

Tags: symfony, configuration, bundle

Given a configuration file like the following:

`my_bundle:
    endpoints:
        api1:
            endpoint1_name: [head, get]
            endpoint2_name: [head, get, delete]
        api2:
             endpoint1_name: [get]
        api3:
             endpoint1_name: [head]`

I want that for each API I can set the endpoints I can configure and for each endpoint get an array with the HTTP methods I want to use.

So, for example, for `Api1/endpoint1_name` I want to use the HTTP method `head` and `get` while for `Api2/endpoint1_name` I want to use only the `get` HTTP method.

**CONSTRAINTS**

Each API has its own endpoints and I want that, during configuration, it is checked the endpoint is supported.
Each endpoint can have some of five HTTP methods: `delete`, `get`, `head`, `post` and `put`.

So, if for an endpoint I set an HTTP method that is not one of the five above, the configuration is wrong.

This is what Ive started to write to check the configuration, but now I receive this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]
>   Invalid type for path "my_bundle_hub.endpoints.api1.endpoint1_name.0".
>   Expected array, but got string

`php
$rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('endpoints')
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayNode('api1')
                            ->children()
                                ->arrayNode('endpoint_name')
                                        ->children()
                                            ->scalarNode('head')->end()
                                            ->scalarNode('get')->end()
                                        ->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end() // api1
                        ->arrayNode('api2')
                            ->children()
                                ->arrayNode('endpoint_name')
                                    ->children()
                                        ->scalarNode('head')->end()
                                        ->scalarNode('get')->end()
                                    ->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end() // api2
                        ->arrayNode('api3')
                            ->children()
                                ->arrayNode('endpoint_name')
                                    ->children()
                                        ->scalarNode('head')->end()
                                        ->scalarNode('get')->end()
                                    ->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end() // Api 3
                    ->end()
                ->end() // Endpoints
            ->end()
        ;`

**How can I check the values?**

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what a configuration !

As far as I know, simple array notation `[]` (with or without keys) in yaml with files is not supported. [Yaml is not aware of languages constructs anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053212/how-to-add-an-array-with-values-in-symfony2-configuration#answer-18053452).

### I would use scalar nodes to list http methods instead to keep the inline "syntax sugar".

This is how I would handle your case

```
endpoints:
    api1:
        endpoint1_name: head, get
        endpoint2_name: head, get, delete
    api2:
         endpoint1_name: delete, post
    # ...
```

… with appropriate configuration class

```
// Some properties inside Configuration class
private $expectedApiMethod = ['get','post','head','delete','put'];
private $methodSplitPattern = '~\s+|\s*,\s*+~';

...

// Inside getConfigTreeBuilder method

// …
->arrayNode('endpoints')
    // Each api's endpoints are arrays with ARBITRARY keys
    // To handle this, you can use "prototype()" method with 'array' parameter
    ->prototype('array')
        // Now, you expect enpoints to hold one or more children (with arbitrary keys). Go for prototype !
        // I advise you to use scalar node to be able to declare method the inline way
        ->prototype('scalar')
        ->end()
        // validation of provided http methods for each endpoint
        ->validate()
            ->ifTrue( function($value) {
                foreach ( $value as $ep){
                    // Set syntax rules for http method enumeration
                    // $this can be used within lambdas since php 5.4.0
                    // Otherwise, just harcode values
                    // The one used here let's you put commas and/or spaces between http method names
                    foreach (preg_split($this->methodSplitPattern, $ep) as $split){
                        if( ! in_array($split, $this->expectedApiMethod) )
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            })
            ->thenInvalid("Wrong http method or syntax error detected.\nExpected values are ".implode(', ',$this->expectedApiMethod)." separated by commas and/or spaces!\n%s")
    ->end()
    // You may want to validate api keys as well here.
->end()
// …
```

`$config` output in Extension class will give you:

```
…
[endpoints] => Array
    (
        [api1] => Array
            (
                [endpoint1_name] => head get
                [endpoint2_name] => head get delete
            )

        [api2] => Array
            (
                [endpoint1_name] => delete post
            )

    )
```

Any wrong configuration would issue Exception/Fatal error.
Note that you can event validate "api" and/or "endpoints" keys the same way.